# Databricks write command to Azure SQL stuck - Very large table

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

We have an extremely large table (> 500 columns, millions of rows) and we're trying to write data from datalake into Azure SQL. The job is running forever and does not complete nor does it throw any error. Below is my code, the same code has worked on many other occasions. Any help appreciated, thank you in advance

```
# Write DataFrame to SQL database
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", "your_table_name") \
    .option("user", connection_properties["user"]) \
    .option("password", connection_properties["password"]) \
    .option("driver", connection_properties["driver"]) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()  


# Get the number of partitions
num_partitions = df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
print("Number of partitions:", num_partitions) // Number of partitions: 600
```

Comment: Two things to try: 1. Run `sp_who2` (or even better `sp_whoisactive`) to get some clues on what the database is doing. 2. Experiment with the batchsize setting as per here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282028/bulk-sql-insert-into-azure-sql-database-using-spark-causes-blocking-contention

Comment: For IO intensive workloads you need to use premium tiers. Are you using DTU-model or vCore Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

**Code:**

```
df.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("driver", jdbc_properties["driver"]) \
.option("url", jdbc_properties["url"]) \
.option("dbtable", "L_Table") \
.option("user", jdbc_properties["user"]) \
.option("password", jdbc_properties["password"]) \
.option("truncate", "true") \
.option("batchsize", 10000) \
.option("isolationLevel", "NONE") \
.option("numPartitions", 10) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
```

- In the above code **.option("batchsize", 10000)** Specifies the batch
  size for writing the data. It controls the number of rows written in
  each batch.
- **.option("isolationLevel", "NONE")** Sets the isolation level for the
  database connection. In this case, it is set to "NONE" which means no
  specific isolation level is enforced.
- **.option("numPartitions", 10)** Specifies the number of partitions to be
  used for parallelism when writing the data. It helps improve
  performance by processing data in parallel across multiple tasks.
- **.mode("overwrite")** Sets the write mode to "overwrite," which means it
  will overwrite the existing data in the table if it already exists.

This code uses the JDBC format in PySpark to establish a connection with the Azure SQL database and write the DataFrame (df) to the specified table (L_Table) with the provided options and configurations.

For example, I have created a SQLtable with 100 columns and rows are written from datalake into Azure SQL. The L_Table consist of have the data for 100 columns.
[image]
[image]

**Get the partition:**
[image]